# Distinct Over multiple columns in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I have a courier_routes table which has two foreign keys to a locations table. The columns in the courier_routes table are start_location_id and end_location_id. (I'm using Oracle)

I want to find the all the distinct locations that the courier has been to in the courier_routes table.

Consider this example

```
|id |start_location_id| end_location_id|...
|1|1|2|
|2|1|3|
|3|4|5|
|4|2|1|
```

I want to get back ids 1 2 3 4 5

My SQL that works is

```
SELECT loc FROM (
SELECT start_location_id AS loc FROM courier_routes 
UNION
SELECT end_location_id AS loc FROM courier_routes);
```

I want to translate this into JPA. Hibernate does not support unions so I thought about doing sub queries. The problem with this is that it could affect performance.

I was thinking of something like (pseudo code...)

```
SELECT id FROM locations where id in (
    (SELECT start_location_id FROM courier_routes) 
       OR
    (SELECT end_location_id FROM courier_routes));
```

Is there an easier way? This table will get big so I really dont want to use sub-queries.

Should I just do a union in java by adding two separate query results into a set?

Thanks

Comment: I would measure the time each of these solutions takes (including the solution of using a native SQL query), and pick the best one. I would guess that the last suggested solution (two queries) is what Oracle would do on its own with the query involving the two subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a join on the two columns in HQL :

```
SELECT distinct loc.id FROM locations loc, courier_routes c 
   where loc.id=c.start_location_id OR c.id=c.end_location_id
```

Hope this helps!